# Issues clicking an element using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Im using this code to explore tripadvisor (Portuguese comments)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Airline_Review-d8729164-Reviews-Cheap-Flights-TAP-Portugal#review_425811350")
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
```

Then Im trying to click the google-translate link

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("googleTranslation").click()
```

But getting this error :-

```
WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (854.5, 10.100006103515625). Other element would receive the click: <div class="inner easyClear"></div>
```

So the `div class="inner easyClear"` is getting the click. I tried exploring it

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page=driver.page_source 
for i in page.findAll("div","easyClear"):
    print i
    print "================="
```

But was unable to get any intuition from this as in what changes to incorporate now to make the "Google Translate" clickable. Please help

===============================EDIT===============================

Ive also tried these

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1200);")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("googleTranslation").click()
```

Resizing the browser to full screen etc..

Comment: I don't see the element with `googleTranslation` class on the page - can you provide a screenshot of the element you want to click? Thanks.

Comment: The problem isn't that the element isn't in view, it's that it's contained by another element that will absorb the pointer event. Can you post a sample of the HTML of that div? Have you tried clicking that div, instead?

Comment: <div class="googleTranslation reviewItem">
              <span class="link" onclick="ta.call('ta.overlays.Factory.reviewTranslate', event, this, '/MachineTranslation?g=1&amp;d=8729164&amp;r=425765103&amp;page=review&amp;sl=pt&amp;tl=en'); ta.trackEventOnPage('Reviews', 'google_translate')">
          <img alt="Google Translation" src="https://static.tacdn.com/img2/buttons/googleTranslation.gif">
        </span>
          </div>

Comment: @shalini Still don't see it - do you have a google translate extension installed may be?..

Comment: @alecxe Ohh my bad, you have to clik on "Protuguese" first. That way it will show Portuguese comments & hence will have "Google Translate" widget along with each comment

Comment: @alecxe https://www.tripadvisor.com/Airline_Review-d8729164-Reviews-Cheap-Flights-TAP-Portugal#review_425811350

Comment: Try to click on `<span>` instead as `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".googleTranslation > span.link").click()`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur not working. You have to deal with each translation one by one, as it comes in a popup

Comment: Ok then try using `ActionChains` as alecxe suggested answer. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me was to use an Explicit Wait and the `element_to_be_clickable` Expected Condition and get to the inner `span` element:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com.br/ShowUserReviews-g1-d8729164-r425802060-TAP_Portugal-World.html")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

google_translate = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".googleTranslation .link")))

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(google_translate).click().perform()
```

You may also be getting into a "survey" or "promotion" popup - make sure to account for those.

Comment: @vinita you should basically iterate over all review elements and search for the "googleTranslation" elements inside..

Comment: @alecxe I tried this but not working :-    for i in driver.find_element_by_class_name("entry"):
    print i      [ERROR : TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable]

Comment: @shalini yeah, that's `find_elements_by_class_name()`, not `find_element_by_class_name()` - watch the `s`.

Comment: @alecxe can u pls help me with the iteration , it isnt working.                                                                                                    for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("partial_entry"):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    google_translate = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".googleTranslation .link")))

    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(google_translate).click().perform()
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_close_x").click()

Comment: @alecxe posted it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940920/selenium-unable-to-click-iterate-through-an-element